# Whats the difference between 'for i in alist' and 'for i in range(len(alist))'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I tried to transform the type of all elements in a list:

```
class Dict1(dict):
    pass
class Dict2(dict):
    pass
def print_type(alist):
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        print(type(alist[i]))
l=[]
for i in range(3):
    l.append(Dict1())


for element in l:
    element=Dict2(element)
print_type(l)


for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i]=Dict2(l[i])
print_type(l)
```

output:

```
<class '__main__.Dict1'>
<class '__main__.Dict1'>
<class '__main__.Dict1'>
<class '__main__.Dict2'>
<class '__main__.Dict2'>
<class '__main__.Dict2'>
```

when I use `for element in l`,the elements' type won't be transformed to Dict2,
however, the `for i in range(len(l))` can do that.

Can anyone tell me the reason for this?

Comment: Because `element=Dict2(element)` does nothing to the list, it merely assigns to a variable `element` repeatedly (with only the last object maintaining a reference)

Comment: please provide this as the actual answer @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: What are `Dict1` and `Dict2` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a list containing 3 elements of type `Dict1`:

```
l=[]
for i in range(3):
    l.append(Dict1())
```

However, when you run:

```
for element in l:
    element=Dict2(element)
```

... assigning `element=Dict2(element)` doesn't change the content of `l` itself. Here, you are just **creating a new object**, named `element`, based on the content of a `Dict1` object, but this doesn't *update* the `element` variable as such.

Thus:

```
print_type(l)
```

prints the original content of the `l` list, with its elements as `Dict1` as assigned in the first loop.

The second loop:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i]=Dict2(l[i])
```

actually **assigns** / **updates** one item of the list `l`, indexed via the `i` variable, with an actual `Dict2` object. The list is updated, so it displays `Dict2` object instead of `Dict1`.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
for element in l:
    element=Dict2(element)
```

`element` is just a variable that's holding an element in the list. Reassigning it just changes what `element` is looking at, not what the element in the loop holds.

It's similar to how `a` never changes here:

```
a = 1
element = a
element = 2

print(a, element)  # 1 2
```

Reassigning a variable has no effect on other code that happens to be looking at the same object.

So why does indexing act as you expect? Because indexing alters the list itself.

```
l[i]=Dict2(l[i])
```

Is actually essentially

```
l.__setitem__(i, Dict2(l[i]))
```

It looks like simple reassignment like the first, but it's actually a mutative operation that changes the contents of the list itself.